# How to create dummy variable based on the presence in the text of 11 digits in a row starting with 8

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, function, dummy-variable

I have a pandas dataframe with texts in column "messages". Some of these texts are large (with dozens of words), some are small. I want to create a dummy "is_number" variable based on the presence in the text of 11 digits in a row starting with 8. How to do it? Should I use regular expressions for it?

Example of a text:

"John got new id number: 82354869135"

This row must have 1 in new dummy column.

Another good example:

"Andrew got new id number82354869135"

As you see, numbers here go without space before. Its ok and dummy variable must be 1.

Example of bad numbers:

"John got new id number: 82354. And mine is: 869135"

This must have 0. So numbers must go in a row

Comment: By "dataset", do you mean a pandas DataFrame?  This does seem like a good regex problem.  Something like `r"\b8\d{10}"`.

Comment: @TimRoberts yes it pandas dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
df["numbers"] = df["messages"].str.count(r"\b8\d{10}")
```

Followup

```
txt = """\
John new is 81234567890 right 81234567890
John new is 8123 4567890 right 81234567890
John new is 812345 67890 right
John new is 81234567890 right 81234567890 81234567890
John new is 8123456 7890 right
John new is 8123 4567890 right""".splitlines()

import os
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( txt, columns=['message'] )
df['match'] = (df['message'].str.count(r"8\d{10}") > 0).astype(int)
print( df )
```

Output:

```
                                             message  match
0          John new is 81234567890 right 81234567890      1
1         John new is 8123 4567890 right 81234567890      1
2                     John new is 812345 67890 right      0
3  John new is 81234567890 right 81234567890 8123...      1
4                     John new is 8123456 7890 right      0
5                     John new is 8123 4567890 right      0
```

Comment: thanks, but it says ```KeyError: 'Requested level (\\b8\\d{10}) does not match index name (None)'
```

Comment: Ooops, I misread the doc.  I'll fix it.

Comment: thanks, but its not dummy variable, its counting. it must be 0 or 1. if there is at least one case than its 1

Comment: I presume you know how to add `> 0` to turn this into a boolean.